# Array becomes larger than declared

Tags: c

I'm writing a function that is supposed to split a string on "-" and return and array containing the parts from the string, so if the string is:
2017-10-23
I want the array to have three elements populated like:
arr[0] = 2017, arr[1] = 10, arr[2] = 23

This is the function:

```
/* 
 *  return a array of the parts of date_string 
 */
int * to_date_array(char *date_string)
{
        int i = 0;
        int f = 0;
        char *tokens = strtok(date_string, "-"); /* get initial token */
        static int arr[3] = {0, 0, 0};
        char *ptr;
        int val;

        /* init static arr */ 
        for (f = 0; f < sizeof(arr); f++)
                arr[f] = 0;

        /* do the split */
        while (tokens != NULL) {
                val = strtol(tokens, &ptr, 10);
                arr[i++] = val;
                tokens = strtok(NULL, "-");
        }

        /* 
         * for some reason arr becomes 12 elements long?
         * I expected it to have 3 elements
         */
        puts("func: to_date_array");
        puts("------------------------");
        for (f = 0; f < sizeof(arr); f++)
                printf("arr[%d]: %d\n", f, arr[f]);

        return arr;
}
```

The function works but I'm really puzzled by the "arr" array. I expect it to be three elements long but when I iterate through it and print every element, it show 12 elements?

```
$ gcc -Wall main.c arguments.c -o timespan 
$ ./timespan 2015-08-10 2017-10-18
func: to_date_array
------------------------
arr[0]: 2015
arr[1]: 8
arr[2]: 10
arr[3]: 0
arr[4]: 0
arr[5]: 0
arr[6]: 0
arr[7]: 0
arr[8]: 0
arr[9]: 0
arr[10]: 0
arr[11]: 0
```

Comment: `sizeof(arr)` --> `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr)`

Comment: next time produce a minimal example. like.. 3 lines?

Comment: thanks for the answer. But why minimal? thought it was good to explain the problem I had thoroughly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sizeof` operand returns a size in **bytes** (where by definition a `char` takes one byte). On your (and mine) machine, `sizeof(int)` is 4, hence an array of 3 `int` takes 12 bytes. See [nucleon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44085399/841108).

Your `to_date_array` is not reentrant. It would be nicer to return a dynamically allocated array (e.g. with `calloc`  ....). Of course you need then to adopt the *convention* that its result has to be later `free`-d (e.g. by the caller).

You could consider also returning a pointer to some `struct` ending with a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member).

You could also pass `arr` (and its length) to the `to_date_array` and have it been filled by that function.

Comment: Thanks for the tips on how to improve the function.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` computes the size of the array in bytes, thus you have to divide by the size of a single element to get the number of elements, thus use

```
sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` returns the number of *bytes* in the array, not the number of *elements*.  On your system, an `int` is 4 bytes wide, so the array takes up 12 bytes.

You need to divide the size of the array by the size of a single element to get the number of elements:

```
sizeof arr / sizeof *arr
```

C does not do any bounds checking on array access - the array is only three elements wide, but you won't get any sort of OutOfBounds exception if you attempt to access elements outside of that range.  The behavior is undefined - your code may crash, it may produce unexpected results, it may work as intended, but the results won't necessarily be repeatable or predictable.

Answer (score 0):

sizeof `int arr[3]` is `sizeof(int) * 3` equals to 4*3 = 12